# Controls randomly not showing in my VB6 software

Tags: vb6, controls

I have a VB6 application with a lot of controls (sometimes even reaching the maximum set by VB6 for a form, we then create custom control to bypass this limit).
On some PC, some buttons/combobox/checkbox disappear. They appear when you click where they actually are and still fire the events, but until the click you're just not able to see it. It's just 1 or 2 controls of the form, everything else is behaving like it should.

It appears on some PC, not all, and the "hidden" controls are not the same from PC to PC (and the majority of the PC the soft runs on have no problem at all).
The Visible property is of course set to true. I can't even reproduce the problem at will...

Do you have any idea of what can cause that? Thank you.

Comment: Not good enough for an answer but:
Maybe part of the limit is being used by other applications? Also, try using the "Windows Classic" desktop theme on Vista/7

Comment: its probably cause by a problem with the memory .. your application is too heavy on its (graphical) memory ... be sure to unload parts that you dont need, and rethink your design as you should not be needing this many controls ... also control-arrays might work better

Comment: @Hrqls Following your suggestion I wanted to give it a try. The problem is that the un-needed controls still in memory are only the one contained in the same SSTab control, and you can't know in what tab they're in unless they are loaded...So you can't load them dynamically (because once they're unloaded you don't have that information anymore)

Comment: @nivolas : i see what you are struggling with now. The SSTab has many tabs, all with its own controls ... I never used the SSTab control, I always used the TabStrip control and used frames to hide and show the controls for each tab. With the TabStrip-approach you can also unload controls, and manage them more easily dynamically if you wish, and you can reuse the same controls on each tab if you want to

Comment: @nivolas : also, if you having this many controls on 1 form (via the SSTab) you might want to reconsider your GUI .. maybe its better to split the SSTAB over more 1 form ?

Comment: @Hrqls I'd like to do it, but it's a very old and unstable application. On some tabs we have 4 or 5 "frame" and given the situation frame 1/2/3/4/5 will be on top, inside a tab. It would takes ages to make it properly and it has no real value in the customers' eyes....So I just try to make it work with workarounds.